# why api calls are not working in git hub page

Tags: javascript, api, github, github-pages, fetch-api

I just finish my news site and while running in localhost of vs code, its working perfectly but on hosting in gh- page api is not working.
here is the link of my repository:-
https://github.com/Ankitsahu640/Express-Time-News

and here is link of hosted gh-page:-
https://ankitsahu640.github.io/Express-Time-News/

[that's how my site seen in local host of vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HFPg.png)

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes, error :-  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 426 ()       newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=dbddeef57b58421aafd6a26534fd9d8d:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your code and I realized the third party api you are sending request to `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=dbddeef57b58421aafd6a26534fd9d8d`

Does not allow you to send request from broswer except from localhost, thats why it works on your local machine.

Here the complete response:

```
{
    status: "error",
    code: "corsNotAllowed",
    message: "Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."
}
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to resolve it

Comment: This restriction is for free plan you can see all plans in https://newsapi.org/pricing , but if you want to use developer plan that is free you should send your request on sever-side